# Get name of file on sever when upload is complete?

Tags: fine-uploader

When using fineuploader to upload files to amazon S3, it's renamed once you upload it to the server. I can trigger an onComplete callback, and also, output some info, but all I get in the responseJson-object is "success" how do I get the name of the file on the server?

```
               callbacks: {
                    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                        if (responseJSON.success === true) {
                            console.log($(this));
                            console.log(fileName);
                            console.log(responseJSON);
                        }
                    }
                },
```

I use fineuploader 3.9.

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the key name for the file in S3?  Did you see the documentation regarding keys?

Comment: I mean the name of the file that the file has if you look in you filebucket on S3, is that what keys are?

Comment: Yes, that is what keys are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to determine the S3 key name of a specific file, you can do so via the `getKey` API method.  For example: `uploader.getKey(fileId);`